# Add Product with multiple categories using Cakephp 3.5

Tags: php, sql, cakephp-3.0, categories, product

I'm working for e-commerce project and i have some problem

Each product can belong to multiple Categories

this is me database table:

```
+-------+-------+
|    Product    |
+-------+--------
|product_id (PK)|
+---------------+
|name           |
+---------------+

+-------+--------+
|    Category    |
+-------+--------+
|category_id (PK)|
+----------------+
|name            |
+----------------+

+-------+--------+
Products_Category|
+-------+--------+
|product_id (PK) |
+----------------+
|category_id (PK)|
+----------------+
```

**This is my code ProductsController:**

```
   public function add()
    {
        $product= $this->Products->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $product= $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Products->save($product)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The product has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The product could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $users = $this->Products->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);

        $this->loadModel('Categories');
        $categories =$this->Categories->find('all');


        $this->set(compact('product', 'users', 'categories'));
    }
```

i have problem when add product

product add successfully in product table

but also i need add product_id and category_id to Products_Category table

i am using cakephp framework

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Please take some time to review your question and fix the formatting issues

Comment: Please also read everything the manual has to say about associations. What you're asking about is all well documented.

Comment: sorry about that, i am resolve this

Comment: at least you have a typo: following cake conventions should be `Categories` and not `Category` (and surely not `Categoty`)

Comment: i replace category with categories but still the error

Comment: You changed even loadModel() call?